# how to upload a excel file in google doc

Tags: api, google-api, google-docs, google-sheets

use C#,want to upload excel file on google doc. bellow syntax use to upload a xls file

```
//use Content-Type: text/csv
     entry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("E:\\Emailcontent.xls", "text/csv");
```

but it's not working ,after upload file convert to csv .But i don't want this conversion.I just want to upload my excel file in my google doc.Help me to upload excel file with out conversion.Thanks in advanced

```
  string USERNAME = "xxx@gmail.com";
            string PASSWORD = "xxxxx";

            // Start the service and set credentials
            DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");
            service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            Authenticator authenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator("TestApi", Google.GData.Client.ServiceNames.Documents, service.Credentials);
            DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();
            // Set the document title
            entry.Title.Text = "Legal Contract";
            entry.IsSpreadsheet = true;
            // Set the media source
            //entry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("E:\\New Microsoft Office Word Document.doc", "application/msword");
            entry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("E:\\Emailcontent.xls", "text/csv");
            // Define the resumable upload link
            Uri createUploadUrl = new Uri("https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full");
            AtomLink link = new AtomLink(createUploadUrl.AbsoluteUri);
            link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
            entry.Links.Add(link);

            // Set the service to be used to parse the returned entry
            entry.Service = service;

            // Instantiate the ResumableUploader component.
            ResumableUploader uploader = new ResumableUploader();

            // Set the handlers for the completion and progress events
            uploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += new AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(OnDone);
            uploader.AsyncOperationProgress += new AsyncOperationProgressEventHandler(OnProgress);

            // Start the upload process
            uploader.InsertAsync(authenticator, entry, new object());
```

Comment: In the future, I would suggest reading the api first before posting a question.  I understand that sometimes it is easy to get stuck and look for the wrong solution, but this would have been easily solved by doing some research before posting.  It will save yourself some headaches for sure! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an xls (Excel) file as a text/csv.  If you want to upload as xls, use

```
entry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("E:\\Emailcontent.xls", "text/csv");
```

If you want to upload as xls, use

```
entry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("E:\\Emailcontent.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Here is the wikipedia/google search that I used:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Answer (score 0):

To ensure documents aren't converted when you upload them, you should also append `?convert=false` to the upload uri.